# Reading local files with JavaScript: single file equivalent for files property

Tags: javascript, html, file, file-upload, dom-events

For reading local files this guide [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles) uses the following code:

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
    ...
```

and

```
<input type="file" multiple>
```

This works perfectly fine, but what if I want to access only a single file, because I am using the `input` `file` type without `multiple`. Is accessing the `FileList` arrays first index the only way?

```
var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
var singleFile = files[0];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use the files[0] as you are accessing a FileList collection http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/#dfn-filelist

The other syntax you could use is `files.item(0)`